# Is there a canonical gem/plugin for a Rails app to use SimpleDb as the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-simpledb

I am thinking of porting a MySQL backed app to SimpleDB. Is there a 'default' choice of which gem or plugin to use for attempting this?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1242

Comment: This doesn't have an answer for your question, but is a good resource you might find useful in the future for finding "canonical" gems: http://ruby-toolbox.com/

Comment: @Arun, I did but that article is almost 3 years old

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about canonical, but running some queries on rubygems.org, I found that [simple_record](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_record) seems to be the most popular at over 31k downloads. Here's their [Github page](https://github.com/appoxy/simple_record). It appears to be a drop in replacement for ActiveRecord.